# Stop the installation from a custom action

Tags: visual-studio, setup-deployment, custom-action

Is it possible to exit msi installar from a custom action without errors?

I am using visual studio setup project to create the msi and I have added a custom action exe to install. If I return a value other than 0 from exe it terminate the installation. But it shows an error. I need to exit installation without showing errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a way to do it using a vbscript custom action from http://chensuping.blogspot.com/2013/05/windows-setup-project-vbs-custom-action.html.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your installer class. I hope it will resolve your problem.

```
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            if (LaunchOnBeforeInstall())
            {
                base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("You cancelled installation");
            }
        }
        public bool LaunchOnBeforeInstall()
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            DialogResult result = frm2.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

And also put **"NOTPREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED"**

[image]